# Allow only selected domain to access http centos

Tags: linux-networking, centos6, apache-traffic-server

I have apache traffic server which caches my webapp and its connected to a CDN. I have to reject all http requests other than my CDN.

IPTABLES rules can't do anything because, as of my knowledge, it won't deal with domain names. hosts.allow and hosts.deny also a no-go.

is there any way to natively block all other http traffic. I don't want to install any third party app because I don't want additional load for my server.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you simply block all traffic at the vhost level, except the ones from the CDN?

Comment: @Vladimir sorry but didn't got you

Comment: Most, if not all, CDN's make their IP-ranges available (to their customers if not the general public) allowing you to create IP-address based whitelists in your firewall...

Comment: Yeah, did that. But I was looking for some do and forget solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to deny everything other than the CDN server nodes to your docroot, or whatever you need protected:

```
<Directory /home/yourdocroot>
allow from x.x.x.x
allow from x.x.y.y
deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: its not apache WEB server, but TRAFFIC server.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that! Then I guess you should take a look at https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/files/ip_allow.config.en.html